# how to extract the first paragraphs from text in dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Consider this dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


mydf <- data_frame(text = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
                            'this is a short text without paragraphs! HA!!!'))
```

I would like to create a column `first_paragraphs` that only includes the first two paragraphs from the text stored in the `mytext` column. As you can see, sometimes there is not even one paragraph (row 3). In that case, leaving the text as-is is OK.

I have tried the following, but without success.

```
#this function finds the position of the second \n in the data
myend <- function(text){
 myend <- str_locate_all(text, "\n")[[2]] %>% as_tibble() %>% pull(end) 
 myend
}

mydf <-mydf %>% mutate(thresh = myend(text),
                       #here I only keep text until that threshold
                       first_paragraphs= str_sub(text, 1, thresh))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.
```

What is wrong here?

expected output is:

```
data_frame(text = c('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ',
                    'this is a short text without paragraphs! HA!!!'))
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `str_locate_all(text, "\n")` returns a list of length 1. To get the two newline positions, use `str_locate_all(mydf$text, "\n")[[1]][,2]`.

Comment: can you make it work in the example? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `strsplit`:

```
mydf$firstparagraph = paste(strsplit(mydf$text, "\n")[[1]][1:2], collapse = "\n")
```

**Result:**

```
> mydf$firstparagraph
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
```

**Edit:**

With OP's updated dataset, below is a way to extract the first two paragraphs of each row of `text`:

```
mydf$firstparagraph = sapply(strsplit(mydf$text, "\n"), 
                             function(x) sub("\nNA$", "", paste(x[1:2], collapse = "\n")))
```

For better readability, you can use pipes from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf$text %>%
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  sapply(function(x){
    x[1:2] %>%
      paste(collapse = "\n") %>%
      sub("\nNA$", "", .)
  })
```

or in `tidyverse`:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

mydf %>%
  mutate(firstparagraph = map(strsplit(text, "\n"), ~{
    .[1:2] %>% 
      paste(collapse = "\n") %>% 
      str_replace("\nNA$", "")
  }))
```

**Result:**

```
> mydf$firstparagraph
[1] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
[2] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
[3] "this is a short text without paragraphs! HA!!!"
```

`sapply` is needed since column `text` now has multiple rows, so `strsplit` will output a list with each element corresponding to a row in `text`. `sub` is used to remove the extra `\nNA`'s for rows where there are less than two paragraphs.

Comment: Hi I am trying your solution with a dataframe that contains multiple headlines and full text, and you code seems to use and repeat the very fist news in the dataframe (disregarding the other rows). Do you know how to fix that? thanks!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I'm not sure what you meant by "contains multiple headlines and full text", also "repeat the very first news in the dataframe". Please update your data as well as provide your expected output in your question.

Comment: as you can see in the updated quesiton, the dataframe contains three rows, each row containing a full-text spanning several paragraphs. I would simply like to keep the first two paragraphs for each row. Of course, some rows may not have two paragraphs. In that case leaving all the text- seems as is seems reasonable

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ See if my updated code works for your new example

Comment: that seems to work! thanks!! I am trying to make it work within a `mutate(firstparagraph =  purrr::map() )` do you know how to slightly adjust your code then! thanks again and then I accept

Comment: or equivalently, with a `str_extract`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Done. This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the first two paragraphs in the variable "first_paragraphs", plus the "thresh variable":

```
mydf <- data_frame(text = paste0(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, '
  'consectetur adipiscing elit, '
  'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '
  '\nUt enim ad minim veniam, '
  'quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. '
  '\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. '
  'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, '
  'sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum'))

mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(thresh = str_locate_all(mydf$text, "\n")[[1]][2, 2],
                        first_paragraphs = str_sub(text, 1, thresh))
```

Comment: hello same problem as below. the code does not work propertly if the dataframe contains multiple news. how to iterate over the rows? thanks!